# Does my child need a passport to fly from the UK to Dublin with Ryanair

Tags: uk, air-travel, ryanair

He has his birth certificate and he will be travelling with me. He is 9.

My child was born in the UK, He is British.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ireland, along with the UK, is a member of the Common Travel Area. British nationals travelling from the UK don’t need a passport to visit Ireland. However, Irish immigration officers will check the ID of all passengers arriving by air from the UK and may ask for proof of nationality. Official advice from https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/ireland/entry-requirements is to carry a British passport, and this is also stated here https://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/government_in_ireland/ireland_and_the_uk/common_travel_area_between_ireland_and_the_uk.html

Ryanair is unlikely to accept anything other than a passport as valid identification.

Comment: I concur with Traveller's final sentence. Regardless of national rules, Ryanair requires either a valid passport or a National Identity Card, even for minors. The UK does not issue ID cards, so the only alternative seems to be a passport.